# How to get only matching records using LIKE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to get the matching records from both the tables

**Matching Table**

```
CREATE TABLE matching (
  ID INT,
  Name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO matching(ID,name) VALUES (1,'Child'),(2,'GrandChild'),(3,'parent')
```

**TreeMatching**

```
CREATE TABLE Treematching (
  ID INT,
  Name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Treematching(ID,name) VALUES 
(1,'Child-Foster'),
(2,'Child-Filly'),
(3,'Child-Ricky'),
(4,'GRandchild-Filmy'),
(5,'GRandchild-Freaky'),
(6,'GRandchild-Frim'),
(7,'Frim'),
(8,'None'),
(9,'parent-John')
```

How to get the matching records from  Tree matching tables

**output :**

```
ID  Name              TName
1   Child           Child-Foster
2   Child           Child-Filly
3   Child           Child-Ricky
4   GRandchild      GRandchild-Filmy
5   GRandchild      GRandchild-Freaky
6   GRandchild      GRandchild-Frim
9   parent          parent-John
```

How to get the same records using like statements I have tried using CONCAT .

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Used like statement in the join and concat function

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Their LIKE's aren't fully compatible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, if you use SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    t.ID,
    m.Name,
    t.Name
FROM matching AS m
INNER JOIN Treematching AS t
ON t.Name LIKE '%'+m.Name+'%'
```

While you try this if you use MySQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    t.ID,
    m.Name,
    t.Name
FROM matching  AS m
INNER JOIN Treematching AS t
ON t.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',m.Name,'%')
```

Regarding the MySQL version, please have a look at the following link.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ce424/2)

Comment: simple thing I have made complicated .. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this (not tested, I don't have a sql-server instance):

```
SELECT M.Id, M.Name, T.Name 
  FROM matching AS M
       INNER JOIN Treematching AS T
          ON M.Name LIKE T.Name + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT  TM.ID,M.Name,TM.Name
FROM    @matching   AS  M
    INNER JOIN  @Treematching   AS  TM  ON  TM.Name LIKE M.Name+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT A.ID, 
    B.NAME,
    A.NAME AS TNAME 
    FROM TREEMATCHING A
    INNER JOIN MATCHING B ON A.NAME LIKE B.NAME+'%'



   ID          NAME                 TNAME
----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           Child                Child-Foster
2           Child                Child-Filly
3           Child                Child-Ricky
4           GrandChild           GRandchild-Filmy
5           GrandChild           GRandchild-Freaky
6           GrandChild           GRandchild-Frim
9           parent               parent-John
```